# kendo ui grid + Hide column in IE11 is not working

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui, grid

i have a kendo UI grid on HTML page. I have used kendo hideColumn() api for hiding column. but when in IE11 browser, i hide column, grid become invisible or sometimes distorted. Kindly help me

Comment: Looks like there was a related recent bug. http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-grid-hidecolumn-bug-in-ie11

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody. It is a bug of kendo ui framework. There are two solutions available for this:

1. Upgrade kendo ui version to latest.
2. After calling hideColumn(), resize Grid by setting its width and height. i have did it as we are not able to upgrade kendo ui version.